# How to read the last few lines within a file using Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am reading a folder with a specific file name. I am reading the content within a file, but how do I read specific lines or the last 6 lines within a file?

```
************************************
     Test Scenario No. 1
     TestcaseID = FB_71125_1
     dpSettingScript = FB_71125_1_DP.txt
************************************

Setting Pre-Conditions (DP values, Sqlite DB):

    cp /fs/images/nfs/FileRecogTest/MNT/test/Databases/FB_71125_1_device.sqlite $NUANCE_DB_DIR/device.sqlite
    "sync" twice.

Starting the test:

            0#00041511#0000000000# FILERECOGNITIONTEST: = testScenarioNo (int)1 =
            0#00041514#0000000000# FILERECOGNITIONTEST: = TestcaseID (char*)FB_71125_1 =
            0#00041518#0000000000# FILERECOGNITIONTEST: = dpSettingScript (char*)FB_71125_1_DP.txt =
            0#00041520#0000000000# FILERECOGNITIONTEST: = UtteranceNo (char*)1 =
            0#00041524#0000000000# FILERECOGNITIONTEST: = expectedEventData (char*)0||none|0||none =
            0#00041528#0000000000# FILERECOGNITIONTEST: = expectedFollowUpDialog (char*) =
            0#00041536#0000000000# FILERECOGNITIONTEST: /fs/images/nfs/FileRecogTest/MNT/test/main_menu.wav#MEDIA_COND:PAS_MEDIA&MEDIA_NOT_BT#>main_menu.global<#<FS0000_Pos_Rec_Tone><FS1000_MainMenu_ini1>
            0#00041789#0000000000# FILERECOGNITIONTEST: Preparing test data done
            0#00043768#0000000000# FILERECOGNITIONTEST: /fs/images/nfs/FileRecogTest/MNT/test/Framework.wav##>{any_device_name}<#<FS0000_Pos_Rec_Tone><FS1400_DeviceDisambig_<slot>_ini1>
            0#00044008#0000000000# FILERECOGNITIONTEST: Preparing test data done
            0#00045426#0000000000# FILERECOGNITIONTESTWARNING: expected >{any_device_name}<, got >lowconfidence1@FS1000_MainMenu<
         1900#00046452#0000000000# FILERECOGNITIONTESTERROR: expected <FS0000_Pos_Rec_Tone><FS1400_DeviceDisambig_<slot>_ini1>, got <FS0000_Misrec_Tone><FS1000_MainMenu_nm1_004><pause300><FS1000_MainMenu_nm_001>
            0#00046480#0000000000# FILERECOGNITIONTEST: Preparing test data done
            0#00047026#0000000000# FILERECOGNITIONTEST: Stopping dialog immediately

    [VCALogParser] Scenario 1 FAILED.
```

Can someone suggest me how to read specific lines, or the last 6 lines within a file ?

Comment: Are you using both `python 2.7` and `python 3.x` ??!!

Comment: You can [edit] your post. Only include _relevant_ tags. Are you actually using `iPython`? What version of Python? Don't just include all the tags that have the word "python" in them.

Comment: I am using python 2.7.3

Comment: @ram Please, do not edit your question to reflect the current state of your code, this makes your question worthless for the other readers. Append it to your question instead.

Comment: sorry. I will correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the last 6 lines of a single file, you could use Python's [`file.seek`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=seek#file.seek) to move near to the end of the file and then read the remaining lines. You need to decide what the maximum line length could possibly be, e.g. 1024 characters.

The `seek` command is first used to move to the end of the file (without reading it in), `tell` is used to determine with position in the file (as we are at the end, this will be the length). It then goes backwards in the file and reads the lines in. If the file is very short, the whole file is read in.

```
import os 

filename = r"C:\Users\hemanth_venkatappa\Desktop\TEST\Language\test.txt"
back_up = 6 * 1024      # Go back from the end more than 6 lines worth.

with open(filename, "r") as f_input:
    f_input.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    backup = min(back_up, f_input.tell())
    f_input.seek(-backup, os.SEEK_END)
    print f_input.readlines()[-6:]
```

Using `with` will ensure your file is automatically closed afterwards. Prefixing your file path with `r` avoids you needing to double backslash your file path.

So to then apply this to your directory walk and write your results to a separate output file, you could do the following:

```
import os
import re

back_up = 6 * 256       # Go back from the end more than 6 lines worth

directory = r"C:\Users\hemanth_venkatappa\Desktop\TEST\Language"
output_filename = r"C:\Users\hemanth_venkatappa\Desktop\TEST\output.txt"

with open(output_filename, 'w') as f_output:
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory): 
        for filename in filenames:
             if filename.startswith('VCALogParser_output'): 
                cur_file = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                with open(cur_file, "r") as f_input:
                    f_input.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
                    backup = min(back_up , f_input.tell())
                    f_input.seek(-backup, os.SEEK_END)
                    last_lines = ''.join(f_input.readlines()[-6:])
                    try:
                        summary = ', '.join(re.search(r'(\d+ warning\(s\)).*?(\d+ error\(s\)).*?(\d+ scenarios\(s\))', last_lines, re.S).groups())
                    except AttributeError:
                        summary = "No summary"
                    f_output.write('{}: {}\n'.format(filename, summary))
```

Comment: I am getting an error : IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\hemanth_venkatappa\\Desktop\\TEST\\Lang'

Comment: again the same error :    with open(filename, "r") as f_input:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\hemanth_venkatappa\\Desktop\\TEST'

Comment: I have added a version which should work with your folder walk.

Comment: thanks !!! but how to remove these extra things like \n and how to pront in separate line : File : VCALogParser_output_MNT.log
['\n', '[VCALogParser] 41 warning(s)\n', '[VCALogParser] 76 error(s)\n', '[VCALogParser] 33 scenarios(s) FAILED.\n', '\n
', '[VCALogParser] Exiting VCALogParser']

Comment: is it possible just to print 41 warnings, 76 errors and 33 scenarios failed in the above output ?

Comment: Yes, you could use a regular expression to extract the text. I have updated the answer.

Comment: If I want to write the solution to a file. I modified the code. is it right ?

Comment: ERROR :   File ".\framework.txt", line 31
    f_ouput.write('{}: {}\n'.format(filename, summary))
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: its working. million thanks. but if the file does not contain warning then it should just print the error and scenario failed. I tried a file which has no warning, therefore it is throwing error on the terminal as Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\framework.txt", line 30, in <module>
    summary = ', '.join(re.search(r'(\d+ warning\(s\)).*?(\d+ error\(s\)).*?(\d+ scenarios\(s\))', last_lines, re.S).gro
ups())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Comment: It means one of your files did not contain the summary lines at the end (or they were in a different format). I have added an exception handler to catch this.

Comment: one of the file does not contain warning then it will throw error as above

Comment: NameError: name 'last_lines' is not defined

Comment: thank you very much. Can you see my question please ? If I read or parse the file completely from the beginning. If the scenario is failed [Scenario 1 FAILED.] then I have to print the test case id [TestcaseID = FB_71125_1]. how can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two methods. If your files are not too big, you can just read all lines, and keep only the last six ones:

```
f = open(some_path)
last_lines = f.readlines()[-6:]
```

But that's really brute-force. Something cleverer is to make a guess, using the `seek()` method of your file object:

```
file_size = os.stat(some_path).st_size  # in _bytes_, so take care depending on encoding
f = open(some_path)
f.seek(file_size - 1000)  # here's the guess. Adjust with expected line length
last_lines = f.readline()[-6:]
```

Comment: file_size = os.stat("C:\\Users\\hemanth_venkatappa\\Desktop\\TEST\\Language").st_size  
f = open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\TEST\\Language")
f.seek(file_size - 1000)  # here's the guess. Adjust with expected line length
last_lines = f.readline()[-6:]
f.close()    // is that right ?

Comment: quite, but you want to use the same filename for getting the size and the content!

Answer (score 0):

Or, essentially, use a for loop to append lines to an array and then remove the nth number of items from the array like:

`array=[]
f=open("file.txt","r")
for lines in f:`

```
array.append(f.readlines())
```

`f.close()
while len(array) > 5:`

```
del array[0]
```

Comment: I wont be knowing number of starting lines to delete it. is there any possible solution ?

Comment: What the hell is that?! Remove this nonsense at once!

Comment: @L_Pav: your intent is good, but neither `array.append(f.readlines())` nor `del array[0]` are doing what you expect. Please test it on your own before publishing.